# $regexMatch alternative for MongoDB < 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB 4.0 and was wondering if the functionality of `$regexMatch` operator can be achieved in versions earlier than 4.2 similar to below that returns a boolean.

```
'$regexMatch': { 
    'input': '$field1', 
    'regex': '$field2'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any alternate option available for `$regexMatch` operator below MongoDB 4.2.

---

You can try the below option, it will match words, we can not say this is an exact regex match,

- `$split` to split `field1` string by space
- `$map` to iterate loop of above split string's array and match `$in` condition if word available in `field2` split string's array
- `$allElementsTrue` to check all elements in available in `field2` then return true otherwise false

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      matchResult: {
        $allElementsTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: { $split: ["$field1", " "] },
            in: {
              $in: ["$$this", { $split: ["$field2", " "] }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8RIyZZoVz2H)

Comment: This approach works, but the result would be `True` if, atleast one of the array elements is in the other array. Can it be modified such that the result is `True` when all the elements in one array are in the other array?

Comment: are you trying to project or format result in query? an aggregation query or find projection?

Comment: I'm trying to project the result i.e the fields that match the criteria. Aggregation query.

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't answer my question in the comments. To add to my comment question, if split array of field 1 is ['a',b'] and split array of field 2 is ['a','b','c'] then the result would be True, if split array of field 1 is ['a'] and the split array of field 2 is same as above then result would be False. Is this possible?

Comment: if field1: ['a'] and field2: ['a','b','c'], then why it is False? can you explain.

Comment: Oops! my bad, the False scenario is field 1 ['a','b'] and field 2 ['a','c']

Comment: False because 'b' is not in field 2. True only if all array elements are present in the other array